# Jquery on page load show div and hide another

Tags: jquery, random, load, switch-statement, refresh

I am trying to make an effect like this: every time you open a page of the site appears a div while another div disappears , and they always alternated . div1 , div2 , div1 , div2 .... I managed to do it by random , as in the code below , but I would like to switch the order every page loads,  refreshs. Could someone help me with these?

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
 switch (numRand) {
    case 0:
    $(".div1").remove();
        break;

    case 1:
    $(".div2").remove();
        break;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to store what was chosen the last time somewhere. A cookie may be the easiest way.

Code doesn't run on SO because of cross-domain issues, but here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30dwa8xd/)

```js
$(function() {
 var numRand = GetCookieValue("numRand") || 0;
 switch (numRand % 2) {
  case 0:
   $(".div1").remove();
   break;
  case 1:
   $(".div2").remove();
   break;
 }
 SetCookieValue("numRand", ++numRand);
});

function GetCookieValue(key) {
 var value = null;
 var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
 for (var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
  var keyValuePair = cookieArray[i].split("=");
  if (keyValuePair[0] == key) {
   value = keyValuePair[1];
   break;
  }
 }
 return value;
}

function SetCookieValue(key, value) {
 document.cookie = key + "=" + value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  This is div1
</div>
<div class="div2">
  This is div2
</div>
```